# How to replace string in php?

Tags: php

I need to replace with space if any character start from B01 to B99 letter and L01 to L99 in string. This points needs to take care

1. Replace all "B01" to "B99" and "L01" to "L99" strings by a space except these 17 characters 1JKFE4P03CDB05071
2. These character(1JKFE4P03CDB05071) always will be of 17 character with L01 to L99 or B01 to B99 or may be other character in between
3. These 17 character can be anywhere in the string not mandatory that it's always in last.
4. This string is coming dynamic everytime. It's not static.

But my code replace B05 with space from both strings.

This is my code. These are example test strings.

```
<?php

    $teststr= "STTARB0520122012       HT      2021B0532B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071";
$teststr= 'PARTSB052014B062014B07HTB062029B0532BB0831B0901283H3 BUB12N EH 5 B 90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071 ';

    $barcodearr = array(
        "B01-B99"=>"",
        "L01-L99"=>"",
        );
        
    foreach($barcodearr as $keycode=>$val)
    {
        
        if(strstr($keycode, '-')) 
        {
           $barexp=explode("-",$keycode);
           $startarr = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $barexp[0]);
           $endarr = preg_split("/(,?\s+)|((?<=[a-z])(?=\d))|((?<=\d)(?=[a-z]))/i", $barexp[1]);
           $startnum=$startarr[1];
           $endnum=$endarr[1];
           $startstring=$startarr[0];

           for($i=$startnum;$i<=$endnum;$i++)
           {
                $doblechar=$i;
                if(strlen($i)!=2){
                    $doblechar='0'.$i;
                }
                
                $findh=$startstring.$doblechar;     
                
                if($startstring=='B'){
                                
                    $space='';
                    for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++)
                    {
                        $space.='&nbsp;';
                    }
                    $teststr=str_replace($findh,$space,$teststr);
                } 
            }
        }   
            
            
    }
```

**Output should be**

```
$teststr = "STTAR  20122012       HT      2021 32B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071";
```

Comment: _"but not from this last word 1JKFE4P03CDB05071(this last string always will be of 17 character"_ - so strip those last 17 characters off then, before you do any replacements - and then add them to the final result again afterwards ...?

Comment: Why is this tagged with MySQL, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: it will take 5 space

Comment: &nbsp;  you can see i have added &nbsp; in code

Comment: As I understand it now all "B01" to "B99" and "L01" to "L99" strings should be replaced by a space except when they are part of sequence of 17 characters. The problem here is that "STTARB0520122012" is also 17 characters long, and it got its "B05" replace by a space. Why?

Comment: STTARB0520122012 have 16 character. It's requirement i have to add space in place of B05 for this string.

Comment: @userdev2025 please comment constructive comments under answers that are not quite correct.

Comment: @userdev2025 one of your comments said `it will take 5 space`. If `B05` creates 5 spaces, then does `B99` create 99 spaces?  Is there any special meaning to `L` versus `B` which is relevant to this task? Your question's desired output replaces `B05` with 2 spaces.

Comment: @userdev2025 please [edit] your question once again to include an array of rest strings which comprehensively represent every fringe case as realistic strings.  Also include the exact desired output for each input string -- an associative array of inputs and outputs will do nicely.  This task is so odd/unique that answers will probably not help any future researchers. Curators have already invested more volunteer time than what this question is worth.  Please tighten up the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single call of `preg_replace()` to make the replacement.

First, try to match the "protected" 17 character substring -- if it is matches, make no replacment and advance the regex engine's position to the end of that string before looking for more matches.

Otherwise, match the ranged substring starting with B or L followed by two digits (but not `00`).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uKq6e))

```
$teststr = preg_replace(
    '/\b1JKFE4P03CDB05071\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[BL](?!00)\d{2}/',
    '  ', // two spaces
    $teststr
);
```

---

If your "protected" string is dynamic, then insert the preg-escaped value into your pattern.

```
$protected = preg_quote('1JKFE4P03CDB05071', '/');
$teststr = preg_replace(
    "/\b{$protected}\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[BL](?!00)\d{2}/",
    '  ', // two spaces
    $teststr
);
```

Comment: Remember that "1JKFE4P03CDB05071" has a "B05" in it, and I think it could be anything from the "B01" to "B99" and "L01" to "L99" ranges. Moreover, it could have "may be other character in between". Yeah, not the clearest question.

Comment: i have tried above. I have added code above this condition if($startstring=='B'){ } but it's not working. It replace every B05 from string

Comment: If you no longer wish to replace substrings that start with `L`, then remove that letter from the character class.  `[BL]` becomes `[B]` ...which can be simplified to just `B`.  `/\b1JKFE4P03CDB05071\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|B(?!00)\d{2}/` @user

Answer (score 0):

Because of the additional requirement added in the comments:

> 90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071 have B20 and according to code char from B01 to B99 will be replaced with space. after that space the last string will be of 17 character but in it B05 should not be replaced with space

We need to take an iterative approach. It may be possible to do this in a more complex regex but it is beyond me. After each individual replacement we need to run again to check whether there is a newly introduced 17 character "word" that needs to be skipped (thanks to mickmackusa for the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique).

```php
<?php

$output = $input = [
    'STTARB0520122012       HT      2021B0532B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071',
    'PARTSB052014B062014B07HTB062029B0532BB0831B0901283H3 BUB12N EH 5 B 90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071 ',
    'XXXXXXXB01XXXXXXX XXB02XX XXB03XX',
    'XXB01XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XXB03XX',
    'XXB01XX XXB02XX XXXXXXXB03XXXXXXX'
];

do {
    $output = preg_replace('/\b([0-9A-Z]{17})\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<!\{)[BL](?!00)\d{2}(?!\})/', '{$0}', $output, 1, $count);
} while ($count > 0);
```

After iterating over the five test strings above we have the following strings:

```
'STTAR{B05}20122012       HT      2021{B05}32B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071'
'PARTS{B05}2014{B06}2014{B07}HT{B06}2029{B05}32B{B08}31{B09}01283H3 BU{B12}N EH 5 B 90000{B20}1FDFE4FS3CDB05071 '
'XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XX{B03}XX XX{B03}XX'
'XX{B03}XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XX{B03}XX'
'XX{B03}XX XX{B03}XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX'
```

The regex explained:

The first option - `\b([0-9A-Z]{17})\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

- `\b` is a zero length match for a [word boundary](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#:%7E:text=A%20word%20boundary%20is%20a)
- `([0-9A-Z]{17})`

  - `()` the parentheses create a [capturing subpattern](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)
  - `[0-9A-Z]` the square brackets create a [character class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)
  - `{17}` the [curly braces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) match the previous token exactly 17 times
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` [backtracking control](https://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail) - skip and fail current match, then move to the next option in the alternation (`|`)

The second option - `(?<!\{)[BL](?!00)\d{2}(?!\})`

- `(?<!\{)` - negative lookbehind - we do not want to find `{B01}` as we have already added braces
- `[BL]` - match one of the characters in the character class - either B or L
- `(?!00)` - negative lookahead - we want to match 01 - 99 but not 00
- `\d{2}` - matches [`\d`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php#:%7E:text=%5Cd-,any%20decimal%20digit,-%5CD) (`[0-9]`) exactly twice
- `(?!\})` - negative lookahead - paired with the negative lookbehind above, so as not to match when braces already added

[PHP docs [negative|positive] [lookbehind|lookahead] assertions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Taking this approach, it does not matter whether your replacement strings start and end with a word boundary (`\b`) as we are introducing our own temporary word boundaries by adding braces (`{}`) around the match - `B##` becomes `{B##}`.

Now we can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to do the final replacement of `B##` and `L##` using the callback:

```php
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{([BL])(\d{2})\}/',
    function ($matches) {
        if ($matches[1] === 'B') {
            $r = '&nbsp;';
        } elseif ($matches[1] === 'L') {
            $r = 'whatever';
        }

        return str_repeat($r, (int)$matches[2]);
    },
    $output
);

var_dump($input, $output);
```

Outputs:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(123) "STTARB0520122012       HT      2021B0532B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071"
  [1]=>
  string(93) "PARTSB052014B062014B07HTB062029B0532BB0831B0901283H3 BUB12N EH 5 B 90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071 "
  [2]=>
  string(33) "XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XXB03XX XXB03XX"
  [3]=>
  string(33) "XXB03XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XXB03XX"
  [4]=>
  string(33) "XXB03XX XXB03XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(177) "STTAR&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;20122012       HT      2021&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;32B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071"
  [1]=>
  string(534) "PARTS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2014&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2014&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;HT&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2029&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;32B&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;31&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;01283H3 BU&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;N EH 5 B 90000&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1FDFE4FS3CDB05071 "
  [2]=>
  string(63) "XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX XX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX"
  [3]=>
  string(63) "XX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX XX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX"
  [4]=>
  string(63) "XX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX XX&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;XX XXXXXXXB02XXXXXXX"
}
```

Piecing the two blocks of code together, the final code is:

```php
$output = $input = 'PARTSB052014B062014B07HTB062029B0532BB0831B0901283H3 BUB12N EH 5 B 90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071 ';

do {
    $output = preg_replace('/\b([0-9A-Z]{17})\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(?<!\{)[BL](?!00)\d{2}(?!\})/', '{$0}', $output, 1, $count);
} while ($count > 0);

$output = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{([BL])(\d{2})\}/',
    function ($matches) {
        if ($matches[1] === 'B') {
            $r = '&nbsp;';
        } elseif ($matches[1] === 'L') {
            $r = 'whatever';
        }

        return str_repeat($r, (int)$matches[2]);
    },
    $output
);
```

Here's a [demo on 3V4L](https://3v4l.org/HduYd) with some additional debug output to following each iteration.

And here's the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/6sbnJZ/1).

Comment: I have tried this it removes B05 from 17 character string also

Comment: It fails with this string $input = 'PARTSB052014B062014B07HTB062029B0532BB0831B0901283H3   BUB12N   EH    5    B    90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071
';

Comment: There is no "word" of 17 chars in that string! `PARTSB052014B062014B07HTB062029B0532BB0831B0901283H3` is 52 chars and `90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071` is 25 chars.

Comment: please see this last string  90000B201FDFE4FS3CDB05071  have B20 and according to code char from B01 to B99 will be replaced with space. after that space the last string will be of 17 character but in it B05 should not be replaced with space

Comment: I have added a loop, only replacing the first match in each iteration, but I suspect/hope that @mickmackusa will have a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

This code should correctly replace characters 'B01' to 'B99' and 'L01' to 'L99' with spaces, excluding the last 17-character segment from the replacement.

```
<?php
$str2 = "STTARB0520122012       HT      2021B0532B        31         01283H3 BU     N   EH    2    B    20000      1JKFE4P03CDB05071";

$barcodearr = array(
    "B01-B99" => "",
    "L01-L99" => "",
);

// Split the string into segments using a regex pattern
$segments = preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z])(?=\d)/', $str2);

// Exclude the last 17-character segment from replacement
$lastSegment = end($segments);
$segmentsWithoutLast = array_slice($segments, 0, -1);

foreach ($barcodearr as $keycode => $val) {
    if (strpos($keycode, '-') !== false) {
        list($start, $end) = explode("-", $keycode);
        $startChar = substr($start, 0, 1); // Get the first character (B or L)
        $startNum = intval(substr($start, 1));
        $endNum = intval(substr($end, 1));

        if ($startChar === 'B' || $startChar === 'L') {
            for ($i = $startNum; $i <= $endNum; $i++) {
                $find = $startChar . sprintf('%02d', $i); // Ensure 2-digit number
                $replace = str_repeat(' ', $i);
                // Replace within the segments except the last one
                foreach ($segmentsWithoutLast as &$segment) {
                    $segment = str_replace($find, $replace, $segment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Reconstruct the string by joining segments
$result = implode('', $segmentsWithoutLast) . $lastSegment;

echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: I have checked this but it's not working