# Replace corrupted alphanumeric id substring containing unwanted spaces

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace, corrupt-data

I have content  that is coming dynamic but some characters from string are missing. I want to replace that characters to make it correct. I have complete order id but in content it's coming with space.

1. I need to replace order id that is coming with space with correct order id.
2. I have correct order id

This is example content:

```
$content = "Order&nbsp;is&nbsp;purchased&nbsp;on&nbsp;23-05-2023.Order&nbsp;is&nbsp;in&nbsp;progress&nbsp and&nbsp;you&nbsp;can&nbsp;see&nbsp;order&nbsp;status&nbsp;on&nbsp;website&nbsp;by&nbsp;enter&nbsp;id&nbsp;JKSZ089P6X07&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;012";

$content = "Order&nbsp;Model&nbsp;is&nbsp;Ford&nbsp;and year&nbsp;model&nbsp;2017.Order&nbsp;id&nbsp;is&nbsp;6FTYF75C7HD&nbsp;&nbsp;715&nbsp;and Vehicle&nbsp;type&nbsp;is&nbsp;commercial.";                     

$content = "Order&nbsp;Model&nbsp;is&nbsp;Mahindra&nbsp;and&nbsp;year&nbsp;model&nbsp;2015.Order&nbsp;id&nbsp;is&nbsp;9PKKJ7FS3CD&nbsp;&nbsp;890 and&nbsp;Vehicle&nbsp;type&nbsp;is&nbsp;personal.";
```

My code:

```
$orderId = "JKSZ089P6X07A07012";
$getChar =  substr(orderId ,0,12);

if(strpos( $content, $getChar ) !== false ) { 
    echo "found";
    $content = str_replace($getChar," ",$content);
}

echo $content;
```

Output content should be

```
$content = "Order is purchased on 23-05-2023.Order is in progress and you can see order status on website by enter id JKSZ089P6X07A07012";

$content = "Order Model is Ford and year model 2017.Order id is 6FTYF75C7HD680715 and Vehicle type is commercial.";                   

$content = "Order Model is Mahindra and year model 2015.Order id is 9PKKJ7FS3CD347890 and Vehicle type is personal.";
```

Comment: Is the space always immediately before the last 3 characters of the order ID? Or can it be different each time?

Comment: Confused. Which one is the correct complete order id? `JKSZ089P6X07A07012` or `JKSZ089P6X07 012`? Where did `A07` vanish?

Comment: I am not sure but till now i have checked content, i have found that space is coming before the last 3 character. Because content is dynamic.

Comment: this is correct order id  JKSZ089P6X07A07012 , In content i am always getting space in order id

Comment: Helps if you show use valid, syntactically correct, PHP code

Comment: Also helps if variable names make sense! Ignoring the syntax error, picking up 12 characters and calling the variable `$fisrt9Char` does not help `$fisrt9Char =  substr(orderId ,0,12);`

Comment: Quote: "I have content that is coming dynamic". The first occurrence of id is correct, the second not. Wouldn't it make sense to try to fix this in the provider of the content?

Comment: It would help if you showed a 1) I start with this. and then 2) I want to get this result. It helps when the description is not too helpful

Comment: Is it okay? i have edited my question.

Comment: @parv with only one sample string, we don't have enough understanding if the variability of your input string.  Please give more samples which cover the trickiest scenarios.

Comment: Any why not just fix the source data? Whatever generated this content clearly knew the correct ID, so that fact that it prints it wrongly the second time is a bug that the creators should simply fix.

Comment: @parv are you collaborating with [this user in an attempt to add ambiguous and strange tasks to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77088293/2943403) ?  What is going on with these oddly mutated strings where a letter followed by two numbers is disruptive to your application?  There is a code smells somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set of sample input data indicates that your whitespace problem consistently occurs after the 12 character.

To repair the string using the `$orderId`, create a regex pattern that replaces the 3 characters after the 12th character with a "one-or-more whitespace expression".  I am wrapping the pattern in word boundaries to eliminate the chance of making false-positive replacements (mangling unintended substrings).  If there is a match, replace it with your known `$orderId` value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/jZ9dl))

```
$regex = '#\b' . substr_replace($orderId, '\s+', 12, 3) . '\b#';

var_export(preg_replace($regex, $orderId, $content));
```

---

If the spaces to be replaced are actually `&nbsp;`, then here is the modification of my above regex pattern. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ElC4g))

```
$regex = '#\b' . substr_replace($orderId, '(?:&nbsp;)+', 12, 3) . '\b#';
```

Comment: It's not working. May be due to &nbsp; . When i inspect content &nbsp; is coming  in place of space.

Comment: Well, my demo proves that my solution works with the sample input in your question.  So the next step is to figure out why your question's input string is not identical to your project's input string.  If you have `&nbsp;` instead of spaces, then please edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: i have updated content in question

Comment: @parv how about this: https://3v4l.org/ElC4g

Comment: Also it could be said that you could clean up your string in advance by replacing all `&nbsp;` substrings with a literal space.

Answer (score 1):

```
function correctString(string $content): false|string {

  $len = 18;       // The length of the id
  $minLen1 = 12;   // The minimum length of the first part of the malformed id
  $minLen2 = 3;    // The minimum length of the second part of the malformed id
                   // Of course minLen1 + minLen2 should be smaller than $len

  preg_match_all("/[A-Z0-9]{{$len}}/", $content, $matches);

  if (count($matches[0]) === 2 && $matches[0][0] === $matches[0][1]) {

    // Found valid id, and also the second, and it they are identical
    return $content;

  } elseif (count($matches[0]) === 1) {

    // Found valid id, but not the second one
    $part1 = substr($matches[0][0], 0, $minLen1);
    $part2 = substr($matches[0][0], $len - $minLen2, $minLen2);
    preg_match_all("/$part1 $part2/", $content, $matches2);

    if (count($matches2[0]) === 1) {

      // Found second, but malformed id
      return str_replace($matches2[0][0], $matches[0][0], $content);
      
    } else {

      // Found no second malformed id
      return false;

    }

  } else {

    // Found no id at all
    return false;

  }

}

echo correctString('Order ... is JKSZ089P6X07A07012.Order is ... id JKSZ089P6X07 012') .  "\n";
echo correctString('Order ... is JKSZ089P6X07A07012.Order is ... id JKSZ089P6X07A07012') .  "\n";
echo correctString('Order ... is JKSZ089P6X07A0701.Order is ... id JKSZ089P6X07 012') .  "\n";
```

Output:

```
  Order ... is JKSZ089P6X07A07012.Order is ... id JKSZ089P6X07A07012
  Order ... is JKSZ089P6X07A07012.Order is ... id JKSZ089P6X07A07012
                      <- Echoing false prints as an empty line
```

Comment: we do not need to find correct id from content. I have already order id as i mentioned above in code $orderId = "JKSZ089P6X07A07012";

Comment: I have tried it. can you please update it as i have order id already